# Can't find 'Scripts' folder or 'pip' file in Python 3.8.2 folder for Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, python-3.8

Can't find 'Scripts' folder or 'pip' file in Python 3.8.2 folder for Windows 10. Trying to install pip for python. Any ideas how I can get past this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Pip should have already been installed when you install your python, if you wanna check if you pip is install try typing pip in your command prompt or terminal and if you wanna see the file directory of the pip you have installed say pip show (here you put name of file like pygame)

Answer (score 0):

As others answered already you should have got pip already as you installed python. Well pip isnt the apllication. You use pip in the application: Command prompt. You have to search for command prompt on your computer (if you have python you already have it installed) and then in command prompt you install packages that you still son't have.
For example you wan't pygame you write: pip install pygame. If you have PyCharm then there is something else you need to do. If you have PyCharm tell me as a comment to this answer and I'll tell you what to do then because command prompt would almost be useless